# How to convert SAS date value say 20NOV2018 to 20 NOV 2018

Tags: sas

I have a date value in SAS like `20NOV2018` which is in date format. I need a SAS function that can separate DayMonthtYear with spaces like for example `20 NOV 2018`.
Which SAS function can solve my purpose?

Comment: You need to say whether the new format is just for display purposes or if you need to store this as a character value.  SAS dates are stored as numbers and you can choose many different formats to display them how you want.  If you just want to change the display then change the format, you can look up all the options online

Comment: It also depends on what you're using this for. In some cases a picture format will work, and in other cases a user defined format (not picture) works. I think this usually comes into play when graphing.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to format, i.e. that is just to display, you should not change datatypes or if you want change datatype(then it is no longer a date but a character value), you can follow @amir answer, it is prefect. otherwise a picture format can help to format your date.

```
 proc format;
picture mydate (default = 11)
low-high = '%0d %b %Y'(datatype=date);
run; 

data have;
input num_date:date9.;
format num_date mydate.;
datalines;
20NOV2018
09SEP2018
;
```

output is

```
Obs num_date
1   20 Nov 2018
2   09 Sep 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single function that will do what you require, so below are presented two alternative methods:

```
/* set up the SAS date required */
data have;
   format num_date date9.;
   input num_date date9.;
   datalines;
20NOV2018
;

/* create char_date1 and char_date2 with spaces in the date values */
data want;
   set have;
   char_date1 = catx(' '
                    ,day(num_date)
                    ,put(num_date,monname3.)
                    ,year(num_date)
                    );

   char_date2 = put(num_date,worddatx.);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are defining the date variable you can use format to change format of your date variable.
The format which you asked goes with mmddyyw. format.
I would suggest you should try using mmddyyw. where w stands from 2 to 10.
trying mmddyy10. to solve your issue and get an output like 01/02/2019.

Cheer's :)